# Overriding routerLink and router.navigate

Tags: angular, angular-router

I need to support having multitenant pages on my app. that said, my routes look like this:

```
/shop-x/products/123
/restaurant-y/products/342
```

now, I want to modify routerLink and router.navigate to be able to (without changing entire codebase):

```
router.navigate("/products/123")
routerLink="/products/123"
```

1. It’s easy to make a new custom router to support .navigate depending on state.
2. but I don’t see a way to override routerLink that `“/products/123”` translates to `“/shop-x/products/123”`, depending on app state. I tried to extend routerLink directive to override `get routerLink()` method, but it sets the variable `this.classes` which is private, so I cannot modify that. If I make a new directive, `routerLinkActive` directive won’t work, and so on.
   What do you think, what is the way to do that?

I want to modify this method:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5205db5564f21c214a96000e018a08f3de7d44d8/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L201-L207